AWS IoT Greengrass V2 API unauthorized request
I've set up the Ubuntu VM under VirtualBox and installed the Greengrass. The installation was successfull which was determined by command "aws greengrassv2 list-effective-deployments --core-device-thing-name Greengrass-UbuntuVM". After that I began to follow the guide on AWS Documentation to connect my client device (ESP32-C3) to the Greengrass core device (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/interact-with-local-iot-devices.html). Before that I made sure that requirements are met and configured the Greengrass service role which was not present (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/connect-client-devices.html#configure-service-role-requirement). I struggle with the usage of Greengrass API which doesn't resolve the request for my client device (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/greengrassv2.html).
curl -i --cert certificate.pem.crt --key private.pem.key https://greengrass-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8443/greengrass/discover/thing/esp_interaction_sensor

The curl commands returns following.
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-type: application/json
content-length: 39
date: Sat, 26 Oct 2024 10:33:09 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: 5991ba75-296f-2f89-a454-80c2d89e84f0
connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-ErrorType: UnauthorizedException:

{"errorMessage":"Unauthorized request"}

I've made sure to deploy all requried services with default configurations. My current policy for the ESP thing look like this.
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect",
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Receive",
        "greengrass:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Running the test client device also return similar exception.
'''
WARN] [2024-10-26T11:25:37Z] [000073e49fe006c0] [http-connection] - static: Unrecognized ALPN protocol. Assuming HTTP/1.1

awsiot.greengrass_discovery.DiscoveryException: ('Error during discover call: response_code=401', 401)
'''
